# Java insert 1dArray in 2dArray and print out

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, bufferedreader

I hope someone can help me.
I read an txtFile in with BufferedReader, put it in a 1dCharArray and now want to insert it in a 2dArray and print it out. My Codeparts:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileReader;
 import java.io.IOException;

 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Sokoban {
 static char spieler = '@', wand = '#', kiste = '$', zielfeld = '.',
        feld = ' ', spaufzf = '+', kiaufzf = '*';

static int spalte, zeile;
static int z, s, chars, lines;
static boolean beendet = false;
static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
static BufferedReader br = null;
static String text;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File f = new File("datei.txt");
    System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());

    String fileName = "C:\\Users\\Tiger\\Desktop\\datei.txt";
    File file = new File(fileName);
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
    br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    for (int code = br.read(); code >= 0; code = br.read()) {
        char ch = (char) code;
        chars++; // Gesamtanzahl der Chars

        if (ch == '\n') {
            lines++; // Zeilenanzahl
        }
    }
    System.out.println(lines + " " + chars);

    spalte = lines;
    zeile = chars / lines;
    System.out.println(zeile + " " + spalte);

    String fileName2 = "C:\\Users\\Tiger\\Desktop\\datei.txt";
    File file2 = new File(fileName2);
    FileReader fr2 = new FileReader(file2);
    br = new BufferedReader(fr2);
    char[] read;

    char[][] room = new char[zeile][spalte]; // Array erstellen

    while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {
        read = text.toCharArray();



        for (z = 0; z < room.length; z++) {
            for (s = 0; s < room[zeile].length;s++) {
            room[z][s] = read[z];}
            System.out.println(room[z][s]);
            }
            System.out.print("\n");

    }
    room[z][s] = 40; // ASCII-Code hex für@

    room[z][s] = ' ';

    room[z][s] = 24; // ASCII-Code hex für$

    room[z][s] = '.';
    room[z][s] = '#';

    while (beendet == false) {
        String eingabe;
        eingabe = scan.next();

        for (int i = 0; i < room.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < room[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.println(room[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }

        switch (eingabe) {

        case "up":
            /*
             * um eine Stelle höher zu gehen muss die Zeilen-Höhe 1
             * abgezogen werden
             */

            spieler = room[z][s];
            if (room[z - 1][s] == feld) {
                room[z - 1][s] = feld;
                spieler = room[z][s];
                room[z][s] = room[z--][s];
                room[z][s] = spieler;
                room[z + 1][s] = feld;
            } else if (room[z - 1][s] == zielfeld) {
                room[z - 1][s] = zielfeld;
                spieler = room[z - 1][s];
                room[z - 1][s] = spaufzf;
                room[z + 1][s] = feld;
                room[z--][s] = spieler;

            } else if (room[z - 1][s] == kiste) {
                room[z - 1][s] = kiste;
                room[z][s] = room[z--][s];
                room[z - 1][s] = kiste;
                room[z][s] = spieler;
                room[z + 1][s] = feld;

            } else if (room[z - 1][s] == wand) {
                room[z - 1][s] = wand;
                spieler = room[z][s];

            }
            break;

        case "down":
            /*
             * um eine Stelle höher zu gehen muss die Zeilen-Höhe um 1
             * addiert werden
             */

            spieler = room[z][s];

            if (room[z + 1][s] == feld) {
                room[z + 1][s] = feld;
                spieler = room[z][s];
                room[z][s] = room[z++][s];
                room[z][s] = spieler;
                room[z - 1][s] = feld;
            } else if (room[z + 1][s] == kiste) {
                room[z + 1][s] = kiste;
                room[z][s] = room[z++][s];
                room[z + 1][s] = kiste;
                room[z][s] = spieler;
                room[z - 1][s] = feld;

            } else if (room[z + 1][s] == wand) {
                room[z + 1][s] = wand;
                spieler = room[z][s];

            }
            break;

        case "left":
            /*
             * um eine Stelle nach links zu gehen muss die Spalten-Höhe um 1
             * abgezogen werden
             */

            spieler = room[z][s];
            if (room[z][s - 1] == feld) {
                room[z][s - 1] = feld;
                spieler = room[z][s];
                room[z][s] = room[z][s--];
                room[z][s] = spieler;
                room[z][s + 1] = feld;
            } else if (room[z][s - 1] == kiste) {
                room[z][s - 1] = kiste;
                room[z][s] = room[z][s--];
                room[z][s - 1] = kiste;
                room[z][s] = spieler;
                room[z][s + 1] = feld;

            } else if (room[z][s - 1] == '#') {
                room[z][s - 1] = wand;
                spieler = room[z][s];

            }
            break;

        case "right":

            spieler = room[z][s];

            if (room[z][s + 1] == feld) {
                room[z][s + 1] = feld;
                spieler = room[z][s];
                room[z][s] = room[z][s++];
                room[z][s] = spieler;
                room[z][s - 1] = feld;
            } else if (room[z][s + 1] == kiste) {
                room[z][s + 1] = kiste;
                room[z][s] = room[z][s++];
                room[z][s + 1] = kiste;
                room[z][s] = spieler;
                room[z][s - 1] = feld;

            } else if (room[z][s + 1] == wand) {
                room[z][s + 1] = wand;
                spieler = room[z][s];
            }

            break;

        case "exit":

            System.out.print("Spielende!");
            beendet = true;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Falsche Eingabe!");

        }

    }
}
```

}

Thats the whole code. I want to move  char (@) in the array with the commands(left,right...)

The first problem comes with the Arrays. If the commands works on it I can't test right now.

Comment: What do you mean by 'it doesn't work'? Please post your declaration and initialization of `room` too.

Comment: You have a typo in the print method, it should be `room[i].length`

Comment: how are you defining z? what if the value of z goes beyond the number of characters available in read - you'll get exception. what if the length of read is more than z - you'll  end up loosing some content. if that's an assumption to the problem, please add more details to understand what is the input and what's needed as output?